# Como autoenviar un formulario en js y php sin entrar en un bucle infinito?

Tags: formularios, bucles

Buenas tardes con todos .
Tengo un formulario que no necesita del boton submit para enviarse a php , el problema es que cada que se ejecuta cae en un bucle infinito , el formulario envia variables de js a php de manera oculta , la idea es que cuando se carge la pagina se envien automaticamente sin que el usuario de click en enviar , pero entra en un bucle infinito .
Dejo el codigo .

********************************** `HTML` **********************************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Problema</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="visitas.php" method="post" id="formulario" name="formulario">
    <input type="hidden" name="timezone" id="timezone" size="20"><br>    
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  //TIMEZONE
  var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  document.getElementById('timezone').value = timezone;

  document.getElementById("formulario").submit(); 
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**********************************************`PHP`***********************************

```
<?php

$TIMEZONE = $_REQUEST['timezone'];

?>
```

---

El problema lo tengo cuando ejecuta "`document.getElementById("formulario").submit();` " . Entra en un bucle infinito , y guarda los dato una y otra vez , cabe aclarar que el nombre del archivo html es visitas.php , alguna idea para que solo se ejecute la primera vez ? ya he buscado con jquery pero no encuentro solucion , muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarás hacer una petición asíncrona con AJAX.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  var formData = new FormData();

  var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

  formData.append("timezone", timezone);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "visitas.php");
  xhr.send(formData);

</script>
```

PHP

```php
<?php

if ( isset($_REQUEST['timezone']) ) {
    $TIMEZONE = $_REQUEST['timezone'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Me podrias ilustrar un poco ?  . El input se quedaba con la informacion de timezone para enviarla a php , con ese codigo no guarda ese input para enviarlo , como podria guardarlo ?

Comment: Si, disculpa que pasé por alto el lado de PHP. Edité la respuesta para que puedas ver cómo recibir parámetros de este modo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda , solo agregar que en la parte de php me daba un error de index que se soluciono con el siguiente codigo .
 if (isset($_REQUEST['timezone'])) {
   $TIMEZONE = $_REQUEST['timezone'];
   } else {
   $TIMEZONE = "";
   }

Comment: Entendido, ya actualicé la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar la funcion document.ready, esta se ejecuta solo una vez una vez cargado el DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
});
```